# python special method __getattribute__

Tags: python, getattribute

I am trying to play with **getattribute** method in python.

```
class Foo:

  def __init__(self):
     self.x = 3

  def __getattribute__(self, name):
     print("getting attribute %s" %name)
     return super().__getattribute__(self, name)

f = Foo()
f.x
```

I get the "getting attribute" printed out, but also a TypeError here:expected 1 arguments, got 2.

So, what's wrong with this snippet?

Comment: When using `super` you don't have to pass `self` to the method.

Answer (score 0):

`super().__getattribute__(self, name)` change this to `super().__getattribute__(name)`

This will fix your problem. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're passing `self` when you call up to `super()`.

`self` is an auto-filled variable, whenever it's used. So, `super()` will be assigned to `self` when it hits the base method. Thus, what you're actually passing to the method is `__getattribute__(super(), self, name)`. Python is smart enough to know to ignore `self` in the count, which is why the error says `2` and not `3`.

This will fix your problem:

```
class Foo:

  def __init__(self):
     self.x = 3

  def __getattribute__(self, name):
     print("getting attribute %s" %name)
     return super().__getattribute__(name)

f = Foo()
f.x
```